# CSF does not open port

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, csf

I'm having a Ubuntu 14.04 server which has a TomCat installation listening on port 8080. I installed CSF today.

Following is netstat -tulpn

```
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      8278/java
```

This is my IPV6 part of csf.conf

```
    # Allow incoming IPv6 TCP ports
TCP6_IN = "20,21,22,25,53,80,110,143,443,465,587,993,995,8080"

# Allow outgoing TCP ports
TCP6_OUT = "20,21,22,25,53,80,110,113,443,993,995,8080"

# Allow incoming UDP ports
UDP6_IN = "20,21,53,8080"

# Allow outgoing UDP ports
# To allow outgoing traceroute add 33434:33523 to this list 
UDP6_OUT = "20,21,53,113,123,8080"
```

Following is the csf -p output

```
8080/tcp   -/6  -     (8278/root)          /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bi... /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java
```

I have restarted csf with csf -r but i cannot connect to port 8080. There are no related error messages on lfd.log and if I diable csf I can connect to TomCat instance running on 8080.

What may be causing this and how to open port 8080 through CSF.

Thank you

Comment: I presume you are trying to connect via IPv6 to port 8080, correct? Because your csf -p output shows that port 8080 is open only for IPv6.

Comment: Yes trying to connect to port 8080 via IPv6

Comment: It's a long shot, but is it possible your IPv6 Address is listed on `/etc/csf/csf.deny` thus blocking your requests when CSF is running?

Comment: Hi, thanx. I rechecked my csf.deny and it does not contain my ip or not even one from my country :(

Comment: What's the output of `ip6tables -L -v -n | grep "dpt:8080"` ?

Comment: `    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp      !lo    *       ::/0                 ::/0                 state NEW tcp dpt:8080
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp      !lo    *       ::/0                 ::/0                 state NEW udp dpt:8080
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp      *      !lo     ::/0                 ::/0                 state NEW tcp dpt:8080
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp      *      !lo     ::/0                 ::/0                 state NEW udp dpt:8080
`

Comment: Ok that's strange. The ports seem to be open at the iptables level. None of which have counted any bytes/packets. Maybe there are some other rules before those that block the requests? I am out of ideas :(

Comment: Yeah :( other thing that confuses me is everything comes to normal when I disble csf

Comment: even if you do: "csf -x" then "csf -uf" ?

Comment: Hi, thank you. csf -uf made port 8080 accessible. Now the issue is even if i remove port 8080 from csf.conf IPv6 config, the ports are still accessible. If I want to block a port which was previously allowed, not removing it from csf.conf and then do csf -r is not enough or do I have to use csf -d for that..

Comment: `csf -x` completely disabled the firewall that's why you can access port 8080 even if it's removed from the allowed ports list. `csf -uf` forced an update on CSF/LFD. You can enable csf by running `csf -e` With `csf -r` you restart the firewall. With `csf -d` IP you can block an **IP address** (not ports). I don't understand the question. You want to block an allowed port without removing it from the allowed ports list? Doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: Sorry, the issue was once I ran csf -uf, I was able to connect through all the ports I mentioned before. To test whether it really worked I removed port 8080 from IPv6 section csf.conf and restarted with csf -r. But even after removing port 8080 from csf.conf I could still connect to 8080 without any issue. I wanted to know how that happened.